# Lucene search value

Tags: java, lucene

```
package com.org.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.FieldType;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInfo.IndexOptions;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.DefaultSimilarity;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

public class Testclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Testclass tclass = new Testclass();
        tclass.searchExactWord("+water-");
    }

    private void searchExactWord(String singleWord) 
    {
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);        
        String dictionaryPath = "c://finaldictionary.txt";

        try
        {   
            //create Index          
            File dir = new File("c://spellchecker//");
            Directory indexDirectory = FSDirectory.open(dir);

            IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDirectory, new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40, analyzer));

            File dictFile = new File(dictionaryPath);
            FileReader freader = new FileReader(dictFile);

            Document document = new Document();

            FieldType fieldtype = new FieldType();
            fieldtype.setIndexed(true);
            fieldtype.setOmitNorms(true);
            fieldtype.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS);
            fieldtype.setStored(false);
            fieldtype.setTokenized(true);
            fieldtype.freeze();

            document.add(new Field("dictionary", freader, fieldtype));

            indexWriter.addDocument(document);

            indexWriter.close();

            //search Index
            IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDirectory);
            IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

            TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(5, true);

            QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40, "dictionary", analyzer);           
            Query query = queryParser.parse(singleWord.trim());

            searcher.search(query, collector);          
            ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;            

            for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) 
            {
                System.out.println(hits[i].score);              
            }

            System.out.println(hits.length);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to do dictionary-based search using Lucene. The dictionary is in text file(finaldictionary) format. The problem is, when i try to search/lookup, Lucene does a fuzzy search and it provides only the number of hits.
Is there any way to determine whether lucene has found the exact value or not
from the dictionary ?

Answer (score 0):

It is *not* performing a fuzzy search.  For the input you've provided, the resulting query will be:

```
+dictionary:water
```

It will not perform fuzzy matching, it will only find documents which contain the term "water".

If you are expecting to find the term "+water-", exactly, in your index, you are not using the correct analyzer to support that.  `StandardAnalyzer` is designed to separate words, and will mostly eliminate punctionation.  You must analyze your field in such a way as to support your search requirements.

Once you've done that, you will need to either escape `QueryParser` characters (the `+`, in this case), or don't use the `QueryParser` at all, such as:

```
Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("dictionary", "+water-"));
```

Comment: (+) and (-) are used as wildcard or escape characters, so that lucene should search only 'water' & not other terms like ('waterbed','waterlog') etc. if i increase the numHits value in TopScoreDocCollector, the hits length also increase, resulting in more confusion. Any way to confirm, if lucene has searched for exact term 'water'